# QEMU: where is dhcp configuration file for vmnet-shared

Tags: qemu, dhcp

When I run virtual machine and attach vmnet-shared IP address is assigned from DHCP

Question: 
Where do I find dhcp default configuration file on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.vmnet.plist`

Comment: Yes I can see entries here however even when I change IP address range this returns to previous configuration after reboot. Any idea how to change IP permanently?

Comment: Same here @RafalNiznik.